# how to get data from callback function in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to get the xml data from the callback function and send the data to another function in Xml Data Class.
Where do I have to return the data to be used outside the callback function ?

This class is responsible for reading the XML file

```
export class XmlData 
{
    private path: string;

    constructor(path: string) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public getXml(callback: Function): void {

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if ((request.readyState == 4) && (request.status < 400)) {
                callback(request.responseXML);
            }
        };
        request.open("GET", this.path, true);
        request.send();
    }

    public callbackData(data: XmlDocument): void {
        var xml = new XmlDocument(data);
        var xmlData: Element = xml.documentElement;
    }

    public reloadXml() {
        this.getXml(this.callbackData);
    }
}
```

---

This is the main app class calls the XmlData Class

```
/// <reference path="XmlData.ts" />    
class App {

    private xmldata :XmlData;
    constructor() {
        this.xmldata = new XmlData("xml.xml");       
    }
    dosome(): void {
        this.xmldata.reloadXml();
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Im my opinion it should be looks like this

```
export class XmlData 
{
    private path: string;
    private xmlData: Element; //xml data on class level
    private listeners: Function[] = [];//array of poreccess listeners

    constructor(path: string) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public get data(): Element { //getter of data
        return this.xmlData;
    } 

    public addListener(listener: Function) {
        this.listeners.push(listener);
    }

    public getXml(callback: Function): void {

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if ((request.readyState == 4) && (request.status < 400)) {
                callback(request.responseXML);
            }
        };
        request.open("GET", this.path, true);
        request.send();
    }

    public callbackData(data: XmlDocument): void {
        var xml = new XmlDocument(data);
        this.xmlData = xml.documentElement;

        this.listeners.forEach((it)=>it()); // when reload operation has done then invoke all listeners
    }

    public reloadXml() {
        this.getXml(this.callbackData.bind(this)); // bind your callback to current object
    }
}
```

So, in the main app you should work with it like this

```
/// <reference path="XmlData.ts" />    
class App {

    private xmldata :XmlData;
    constructor() {
        this.xmldata = new XmlData("xml.xml");   
        this.xmldata.addListener(()=>this.onXmlReloaded()); // here we add some listener to xmldata loader  
    }

    private onXmlReloaded(){ // here we process received data outside of xmldata class
      let receivedData =  this.xmldata.data;
      //some code here
    }        

    dosome(): void {
        this.xmldata.reloadXml();
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.listeners.forEach((it)=>it()); // when reload operation has done then invoke all listeners` when im debugging that line fails with this error : *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined*

Comment: this is the error from  Visual studio : 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'forEach' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Hmm, I made for you some changes

Comment: The issue happens because you callback in previous case had bound to global scope, so, there is no listeners ( listeners equals to undefined) in this scope

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem its not your suggestion, but its look like that

```
public callbackData(data: XmlDocument): void {
        var xml = new XmlDocument(data);
        this.xmlData = xml.documentElement;
        //this.listeners.forEach((it) => it());
        DockContainer.prototype.abc(this.xmlData);
```

}

```
public abc(data: any) {
            console.log(data);
}
```

if you want to get acces to another function in the same class, need to specify the full path to this function